# Zend_Form outputs without main HTML HEAD BODY tags

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

In my `index/index` action, I'm calling a form class that I created, and output the form in the `index.phtml` view like this

```
<?php
echo $this->form;
```

But when I view the page source, all I'm getting is the form markup. I don't get any `HTML HEAD BODY` tags to make this a valid markup page. How do I add these to all my pages?

I have `layouts/scripts/layout.phtml` but I'm not sure what's the correct way to use it.

Comment: Are you using Zend Application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have not *enabled* the layouts.

The typical way to so this is via your `configs/application.ini file:`

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
```

The file `application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml` should have the html code for your template, typically employing (as noted in the answer by @Alkexander) the view-helpers `headLink()`, `headScript()`, etc.

See [Zend Framework: Documentation: Using Zend_Layout](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.layout.usage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use common layout. In this layout with help of View Helpers create doctype, head...

```
$this->getHead('jquery');
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/styles/common.css');
echo $this->headTitle();
echo $this->headMeta();
echo $this->headScript();
echo $this->headLink();
echo $this->headStyle();
```